# Is there a better way to handle this?

Tags: coding-style, if-statement, nested

I've come across this particular pattern a few times now and it's somewhat annoying to have to declare the flag variable in order for this to work correctly. Is there a simpler way to arrange this code that I'm just not seeing?

```
flag = true
if x.is_okay?
  some_stuff_that_needs_x_to_be_okay
  if some_condition_that_depended_on_x
    actually_important_stuff
    flag = false
  end
end

if flag
  do_something_when_important_stuff_did_not
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way without the flag variable. It's reasonable if `do_something_when_important_stuff_did_not` is a single, simple statement, such as a method call.

```
if x.is_okay?
  some_stuff_that_needs_x_to_be_okay
  if some_condition_that_depended_on_x
    actually_important_stuff
  else
    do_something_when_important_stuff_did_not()
  end
else
  do_something_when_important_stuff_did_not()
end
```